# unlist data into single line in R

Tags: r

I have a array as like this

```
DATA01   Data03  Sam2
23.2     W.343    25
67.9     3.4      3.6
2.3
```

Need to convert as like this

```
DATA01     
23.2         
67.9           
2.3
Data03
W.343
3.4
Sam2
25
3.6
```

I tried with t (Transpose)

```
t(paste(unlist(Data), collapse =" "))
```

but It is not solving the issue

Comment: Can you give the data unambiguously with `dput(x)`? Is `DATA01` a column header or is it data (and this is a matrix)?

Comment: Try another `t`, as in `t(t(unlist(Data)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass column name and value to construct such one column dataframe.

```
data.frame(value = unlist(mapply(function(x, y) c(y,na.omit(x)), 
                          df, names(df))), row.names = NULL)
```

Or using `purrr` :

```
library(purrr)

imap(df, ~c(.y, na.omit(.x))) %>% flatten_chr() %>% data.frame(value = .)

#    value
#1  DATA01
#2    23.2
#3    67.9
#4     2.3
#5  Data03
#6   W.343
#7     3.4
#8    Sam2
#9      25
#10    3.6
```

**data**

Assuming this is your data :

```
df <- structure(list(DATA01 = c(23.2, 67.9, 2.3), Data03 = c("W.343", 
"3.4", NA), Sam2 = c("25", "3.6", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
df

#  DATA01 Data03 Sam2
#1   23.2  W.343   25
#2   67.9    3.4  3.6
#3    2.3   <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Your idea leads me to `data.frame(value = na.omit(unlist(rbind(names(df),df))))`, or `as.vector(na.omit(unlist(rbind(names(df),df))))` if vertical arranging is not important.